# Regex backreference of optional group (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, reference

I have the following string:

```
<CODE MUST OPTIONAL1 : OPTIONAL2> OPTIONAL3 </CODE MUST OPTIONAL1>
```

I tried using regex to parse it and I'm using the following:

```
/<CODE\s+([\w]*\w)(?:\s+([\w ]*\w)\s*)?(?::\s+([\w ]*\w)?))?\s*>(?:([^<]*?)<\/CODE /1 /2>)?/i
```

of the problem is when there is no OPTIONAL1, for example:

```
<CODE A B : C> ABC </CODE A B> (working)
<CODE A : C> ABC </CODE A> (not working)
<CODE A : C> ABC </CODE A > (working) ---> I needed to add an extra
space at the end of the first back reference.
```

Can you help me here! I must be doing something wrong! also I wanted to ask you performance wise what do you suggest me to change in the original regexp. (BTW... all MUST, OPTIONAL1, OPTIONAL2, OPTIONAL3 can be either text or number) :)

Comment: Use an optional group around the backreference.

Comment: Try `/<CODE\s+([\w]*\w)(?:\s+([\w ]*\w)\s*)?(?::\s+([\w ]*\w)?))?\s*>(?:([^<]*?)<\/CODE /1(?: /2)?\s*>)?/i`.